# Powershell script to automate button click

Tags: windows, powershell

Through powershell we need to auto search a site and click on it. That is after accessing the site and then in search box we entered the word for eg: "Linux" to search and then we need to press a button. While inspecting the button its showing as follows:

```
<button class="ico-search" onclick="frmSiteSearch_conductSearch(); return false;"></button>
```

Script Iam trying are as follows but in search box its getting the correct word but button is not clicking.

```
$searchword = "linux" 
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("search.geo.com") 
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100} 
$ie.document.getElementById("frmSiteSearch").value= "$searchword" 
start-sleep 5
$ie.document.getElementById("ico-search").Click()
```

Through powershell can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: `getElementById("ico-search")` <> `<button **class**="ico-search" ...`

Comment: @gvee Can you please write it in more detail. Sorry I am not a programmer.

Comment: your button has a **class** of "ico-search". Your JavaScript is calling a function by the name of getElementBy **Id** (). A class is not the same as an Id, therefore the function isn't finding an element to attach the `Click()` event to!

Answer (score 0):

```
$toclick = $ie.document.getElementById("ico-search")
$toclick.click()
```

Try that, I think you are trying to call the click method on a search instead of an actual element.

Comment: It seems its a click method on a search. While inspecting the button it shows as <button class="ico-search" onclick="frmSiteSearch_conductSearch(); return false;"></button> . Can you please help me on this.